# Cannot connect Celery to RabbitMQ on Windows Server

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to setup rabbitMQ to use as a message broker for Celery. I am trying to set these up on a Windows Server 2012 R2. After I start the rabbitMQ server using the RabbitMQ start service on the applications menu, I try to start the celery app with the command.

```
celery -A proj worker -l info
```

I get the following error after the above command.

```
[2018-01-09 10:03:02,515: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://
guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [WinError 10042] An unknown, invalid, or unsupported
option or level was specified in a getsockopt or setsockopt call.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
```

So, I tried debugging, by check the status of the RabbitMQ server, for which I went into the RabbitMQ command prompt and typed `rabbitmqctl status`, on which I got the following response.

[image: Response on checking RabbitMQ status]

These are the services that I used to start RabbitMQ and the RabbitMQ command line

[image: RabbitMQ services]

Here's my Django settings for Celery. I tried putting ports and usernames before and after the hosts, but same error.

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://localhost//'
```

What is the issue here? How do I check if the RabbitMQ service started or not? What setting do I need to put on the Django Settings file.

Comment: The RabbitMQ team monitors [this mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) and only sometimes answers questions on StackOverflow. Having said that, did you install Erlang and RabbitMQ using an administrative account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fighting the same issue. Ended up downgrading amqp to 2.1.3 based on the open issue in py-amqp:

https://github.com/celery/py-amqp/issues/130

1. Uninstall amqp using `pip uninstall amqp`
2. Install amqp using `pip install -Iv amqp==2.1.3`

Comment: Yah I did the same. Was planning to post the answer here, but never the less take the 15 points.